# MongoDB Mongoose Group by together with count

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am very new to MongoDB and has to work with a MongoDB based analytics API.

I have model called Session

```
user: { id: Number, name: String, email: String },
ipAddress: String,
device: String,
createdAt: Date
```

My requirement is

**Get total number of sessions in last 7 days and group it by the date.**

Hope my question is clear to you.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`$group`**, to group the similar records, and then **`$sum`** accumulator in $group stage to count the records.

```
let date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 7);

db.collection("sessions").aggregate({$match:{createdAt: {$gte: date }}},
     {$group:{
         _id: "$_id",
         count: {$sum: 1},
         createdAt: {$first: "$createdAt"},
     }},
     {$group: {
         _id: "$createdAt",
         countAccToDate: {$sum: "$count"},
         totalCount: {$first: "$count"}
     }})
```

Explanations:

First I am filtering the records acc to date **$match** criteria,

Then I am grouping them by _id in **first $group stage**, this way we are getting total no of sessions (even one use can have multiple sessions OR there can be more than one session for the same date) that way we get total no of sessions.

With **`$first`** you can project the first value matched in $group stage.

then in the **second $group stage**, I am grouping them according to createdAt, and counting the total no of sessions for that time.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate()-7);
db.getCollection('sessions').aggregate([
{$match: {'createdAt': {$gt: d}}}
])
```